# python threading multiple functions every minute

Tags: python, multithreading

I have several functions I would like to run in an infinite loop simultaneously, but all functions should be run at different intervals. For example, the following code:

```
while True:
   functionA()
   after 1 minute repeat
   functionB()
   after 2 minutes repeat
```

I know hot to work with time.sleep or dateime.now(), but I do not know how to get functionA and B to run and wait independently of each other in the same file.

Comment: You may want to look at a threading solution that releases the GIL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from threading import Timer

class Interval(object):
    """Interface wrapper for re-occuring functions."""

    def __init__(self, f, timeout):
        super(Interval, self).__init__()
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.fn = f
        self.next = None
        self.done = False
        self.setNext()


    def setNext(self):
        """Queues up the next call to the intervaled function."""
        if not self.done:
            self.next = Timer(self.timeout, self.run)
            self.next.start()

        return self


    def run(self):
        """Starts the interval."""
        self.fn()
        self.setNext()
        return self


    def stop(self):
        """Stops the interval. Cancels any pending call."""
        self.done = True
        self.next.cancel()
        return self
```

Pass the functions and timeouts as arguments. The Timer class from the threading module does most of what you need (running a function after a certain time has passed) the wrapper class I added just adds the repetition, makes it easy to start it, stop it, pass it around, etc.

Comment: Can you explain what the problem was, and what the solution does differently?

Comment: @PeterWood added a bit of explanation.